# Strange behavior of 'this' with inheritance

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I'm having trouble understanding the value of `this` in the following example:

```
struct A {
  int i;

  void bar() {
    cout << this << endl;
  }
};

struct B : public A {
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct C : public B {
  void foo() {
    printf("hello world!\n");
  }
};

int main (int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  C* c = new C; 
  cout << c << endl;
  c->bar();
  return 0;
}
```

Both times I print the pointer to the console, I get different values. I would expect it to be the same, as they refer to the same instance both times?!

If I remove either the virtual function or the `int i` in `A` it goes away. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But it refers to differnt things.

```
void bar() {
    cout << this << endl;
  }
```

Here `this` has a type `A*`. It points to the part of the object that is `A`.

```
out << c << endl;
```

Here `c` is a `C*` and points to the part of the object that is `C`.

If the `A` object lines up exactly with the `C` object the pointers are the same. If they do not (like when C contains other members (hidden pointer to the vtable) and thus the 'A' part is offset from the start of the larger object) then the pointers are not necessarily the same.

Comment: Usually even if `C` has extra members, they will be the same.  However, if `C` has _any_ `virtual` functions, it's common to put those before any members.

Comment: sounds reasonable, i am really surprised however. is there any possibility to get the `this` of the class that was originally created?

Comment: For extra fun, try adding this in `main`: `A* c2 = c; cout << c2 << endl;`

Comment: @lucas clemente: Yes dynamic_cast<C>(this) will return the parent pointer (if it is a C or NULL if is not a C).

Comment: This also means that i can't just `delete` an instance casted from `C` to `A`, right?

Comment: @lucas clemente: Correct. The way to get around this is to have a virtual destructor in A. This will force the destructor to chain to its parent class before starting the destruction.

Answer (score 2):

It is a compiler optimization.  The A struct doesn't have any virtual methods so it doesn't need a v-table.  No point storing a pointer to it in an object of type A.  Which makes the object layout different between objects of type A and C since C *does* need a v-table.  The compiler makes up the difference by incrementing *this* before calling a method of A.

Add an arbitrary virtual method to A to make the pointers match.

Comment: Even with a virtual method the pointers aren't the same, I just tried it out.

Comment: Works on my machine™.  Makes sense to me anyway.